# Is it necessary that the order of the image divides the order of the domain in an onto group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi:G\to H$ be an ***onto*** group homomorphism. Is it necessary that $|G|$ is a multiple of $|H|$, provided that both groups are finite?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By the first isomorphism theorem, 
$$G/\ker(\phi)\cong H.$$
Therefore
$$\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \ker(\phi)\rvert \cdot \lvert H \rvert.$$